# Unable to click google oauth button in webview android app(capacitor)

Tags: android, web-applications, webview, capacitor

I am working on building my web app into android app using capacitor. my google oauth button is not getting trigger on first load. It works only when I run apply changes and restart activity.

I tried enabling javscript in my mainActivity.java file.but its not working
`public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // Uncomment if you have a custom layout

```
    WebView webView = getBridge().getWebView();
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Enable JavaScript if needed
    
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    WebView webView = getBridge().getWebView();
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

}`

and this is my androidMainfest file
`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="oauth" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>

<!-- Permissions -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

`
SignupComponent react component
`const onOAuthBtnClick = () => {
    OAuth2Client.authenticate(oAuthOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        const loginObj =
          Object.values(response)?.find(({ access_token }) => !!access_token) ||
          {};

```
    googleLogin(loginObj)
      .then((res) => {
        const userObj = getUserData();
        if (res.dcs[0]?.id) {
          saveUserDCId(res.dcs[0]?.id || null);
        }
        saveUserData({ ...userObj, ...res });
        history.push("/app");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setSubmitting(false);
      });
  })
  .catch((reason) => {
    console.error("OAuth rejected", reason);
  });
```

};
return (

Sign in with Google

);
};`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.